# How to use JQuery .each( ) to iterate through 47 divs?

Tags: jquery

I have a basic understanding of how .each() works based on whats in the jquery docs, but I dont really understand how I can apply it to something that has a large amount of elements. I have a map I made using SVG. currently each section of the map lights up on a onmouseover function.

```
      $('.shape').mouseover(function(){
    // $('.shape').css({fill:#5df8b8;})
    shape_id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log($(shape_id));
    $("#" + shape_id).css("fill", "#5df8b8");
    $('.hidden').each(function(i){
      //show each div on hover over 
    });


  });
  $('.shape').mouseleave(function(){
    console.log("you left a zip");
     $('.shape').css("fill", "white");
     $('.hidden').hide();
  });
```

I have a div for each section of the map. each div containing information on the area. I want to be able to make each div display depending on where you hover on the map is there something better than .each() for this case?

Comment: Do you have a way to identify the `.hidden` element that is related to the currently hovered `.shape` element, like a certain class, the same index etc ?

Comment: @adeneo Im not so sure what you mean but each div has its own id and the hidden class. the svg elements also have the same id that the divs have

Comment: @user2302869 better would be to provide an sample html template in fiddle

Comment: @Alnitak so do you just troll stackoverflow wishing you had a dollar? I'm sure you can make more money doing better things with your time.

Comment: They can't have the same ID, that would be invalid markup ?

Comment: @user2302869 no, it's just a pet peeve of mine :)

Comment: @Bingo Unfortunately I cant get the styles for my svg to load on jsfiddle therefore the hoverover effect does not work since svg uses a specified css sheet.

Comment: You don't usually need to use `.each()` to bind event handlers. Just bind a handler to the collection, and use `this` in the handler to get the target of the event.

Comment: @adeneo I thought that maybe if i gave them the same id i could use that to my advantage when i make the relation between the div and the map

Comment: You can use similar IDs. Give `.hidden` IDs like `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. and give the corresponding `.shape` elements IDs like `shape-foo1`, `shape-foo2`, etc. Then you just concatenate `'shape-'+this.id` to get the corresponding shape.

Comment: Giving them the same `id` would render your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" reference to the element in the mouseover and mouseleave events refers to the div that triggered the event. You can use that without have to loop through all the divs in the map. See below code. I created a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvArZ/) that is a working example.

```
<div class="transparent"><img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" /></div>
<div class="transparent"><img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" /></div>
<div class="transparent"><img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/images/logos/google_logo_41.png" /></div>


$("div").bind("mouseover", function(el, a){
$(this).removeClass("transparent")
})
.bind("mouseleave", function(el, a){
$(this).addClass("transparent")
})
```